# React TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, logical-operators

I building small react app. Main task is creating app about pokemons with PokeApi. When I clicking on pokeCard, on my sidebar must to display main information about pokemon. So, I want to be displayed number of pokemon. How we know, all numbers starts at #. But in PokeApi numbers of pokemons are not starts with # and doesn't containt any 0. For example, number of Charmander is #004, but in PokeApi Id is 4.
So, I created condition with logical operators. Please, look:

```
  {(pokemon.id.length === 1 && <span>#00{pokemon.id}</span>) ||
      (pokemon.id.length === 2 && <span>#0{pokemon.id}</span>) ||
      (pokemon.id.length === 3 && <span>#{pokemon.id}</span>)}
```

I hope I created right. But, on my screen I see `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` . I think, it's because ,before I will be clicking, pokemon.id is undefined. I try to create `typeof(pokemon.id) == "undefined" && <span>loading</span>` , but it doesn't work.

It's code, how I set Pokemon.

```
const [SelectedPokemon, setSelectedPokemon] = useState([]);

 const fetchPokemonDetails = (pokemonId) => {
    fetch(`${API_URL}${pokemonId}`)
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setSelectedPokemon(result);
      }, setLoadingForSelectedPokemon(false))
      .catch((error) => console.log("Error:", error));
  };
```

Can you help me fix it?

Comment: means `id` is undefined.... So sounds like you are rendering something before it is set.

Comment: @epascarello How I understand, it working how you say. But I dont know how to avoid it.
It must respond when I clicked on the button.

Comment: Hard to know without seeing your React code on how you are setting `pokemon`

Comment: @epascarello I editing my post, and adding code , how I setting pokemon in bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the property before its defined. Can you try with the code snippet below?

```
{pokemon.id !== undefined ? 
(pokemon.id.length === 1 && <span>#00{pokemon.id}</span>) ||
      (pokemon.id.length === 2 && <span>#0{pokemon.id}</span>) ||
      (pokemon.id.length === 3 && <span>#{pokemon.id}</span>)
: null}
```

Comment: I tried. And it doesn't showed no one error. Also it doesn't show pokemon.id.

Comment: It's working your solution. I just format type of id (number) to string.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the upvote. It would be cool if you could choose this as the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure the data called properly.
it is occurred because your data is not ready yet.

the code should be like this

```
{(pokemon && pokemon.id.length === 1 && <span>#00{pokemon.id} 
 </span>) ||
  (pokemon && pokemon.id.length === 2 && <span>#0{pokemon.id} 
 </span>) ||
  ( pokemon && pokemon.id.length === 3 && <span>#{pokemon.id} 
 </span>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are trying to use `pokemon.id` before it is actually defined. I would recommend putting your statements in another if like:

```
{ pokemon.id ? this.handleId(pokemon.id) : "" }
```

where

```
handleId = (id) => {
  let holder = "#000";
  let arr = holder.split("");
  id.split("").reverse().map((e, i) => arr[3 - i] = e);
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

I believe this solves your problem and `handleId` can be used with an `id` of any length.

Comment: I tried. And its showed - `pokemon.id.split is not a function` .  Maybe, its because when I set Pokemon, I set it like as object

Comment: What do you get when you log the pokemon object?

Comment: this one:
{abilities: Array(2), base_experience: 64, forms: Array(1), game_indices: Array(20), height: 7, …}

Comment: Well, from your comment it seems that this object does not seem to have an `id` property.

Comment: So, how you will explain that if I have only `{pokemon.id}` when I clicked, I see pokemon id?

Comment: For real, if I I open my log, I see key id with its property. I dont copy all, because it have many properties, and it looks not good here.

Comment: I change my problem with id. It was because id is number.
So I try your code snippet, and I have an error:
`TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '3' of string '#000'`

Comment: I edited the answer and it should work if you convert the integer id to a string in the method.